# Relaying outgoing mail from another server

Tags: emailrelay

Sorry if I asked you the same question. Two days back Softlayer has put restriction to send outgoing mails from port25 on there datacentres.

I have a server **Server1** there which is hosting 35 websites. Some on shared IP some on Dedicated IP's ans other IP's are in pool.

My server have cPanel installed in it, and I configured sending port to 26, 587, 2525 by going

Service Manager>Exim Mail Server (on another port)

Allow exim to listen on a port other than 25. [26,587, 2525]

After this I test sending an email and the email didn't come through and queued up in server.

Since I cannot move my DC I'm looking for relaying outgoing mails from another server **Server2**.

Did anyone knows what should I do so that all my domains emails will go to-n-fro from **Server2** and on receiving an email on my gmail from the domains, I should see email is sent from specific IP, not from shared IP of **Server 1 & Server 2** but the dedicated IP's provided to specific domains on **Server1**.

Also I'm using PowerMTA and put up sending port to 2526 but that emails are also not going and queuing up. On my **Server1** I can't telnet to gmail server as well

telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
shows trying and then dead...

Please help if anyone knows anything on this.

Thanks & Regards
Kishan Giri